# Subscribe Mailchimp from controller without form CakePHP

Tags: json, cakephp, mailchimp

I am creating a webservice for an Android application.
The Android application have a "Newsletter subscription" option with 3 fields :
- email
- surname
- phone_number

The application send theses data in json format to the `NewsletterControlleur.php` on my web service:

```
{
    "Newsletter":{
        "user":{
            "first_name":"Hugo",
            "surname":"Dumoulin",
            "phone":"0606060606",
            "email":"hugo@gmail.fr"
        }
     }
}
```

I now need to add this person to my Mailchimp subscriber list.
How can I do this from the controller with my json data and without any form ?

I know I have to post theses data to an url like this (that mailchimp gave me) :

> http://******.us1.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=************&id=********

Anyone known how I can manage to do this ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: i used a plugin for this as https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-mailchimp

Comment: @Abhishek I am going to take a look thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That list-manage URL is intended to be hit by a user with a browser, and there are several different things that could trip up your process. Specifically, MailChimp can sometimes show a CAPTCHA if it thinks the subscriptions are coming from a bot.

### Prerequisites

The better way is by using MailChimp's API. You'll need four things:

1. **Your datacenter** - This is something like `us7` and it's at the beginning of the URL when you're logged in to MailChimp. I'll use us7 below, but you should substitute your own.
2. **Your API Key** - you can find this in the 'extras' portion of your account settings or [click here](https://admin.mailchimp.com/account/api-key-popup).
3. **Your List ID** - You can find in your settings (choose 'name and defaults' link from the 'settings' menu). It'll look something like this: `1295ff8fdb`.
4. **Relevant Merge Tags** -- You'll just need to know what the merge tags are for first name, surname, and phone. I'll assume those are `FNAME`, `LNAME`, and `PHONE` below, but you'll want to substitute your own in order for this to work properly.

Once you have those things, you can use any HTTP client (like [Cake's](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/httpclient.html)) to make the subscription.

### Authentication

v3 of MailChimp's API uses [HTTP Basic Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). This is a header-based authentication scheme and the vast majority of HTTP libraries support this easily out of the box. If you have to do this by hand, you pass a header named `Authorization` and the contents of that header are the word "Basic" followed by a space and then your username and password, separated by a colon, Base64 encoded. For MailChimp, the username is irrelevant and you use your API Key as the password.

Fortunately, Cake's client offers support out of the box. To use it, just pass an `auth` key into the options parameter of the request. The value should look like this: `array('type' => 'basic', 'username' => 'anything', 'password' => $MAILCHIMP_API_KEY)`. (Note, the username is not used by MailChimp, you can pass any string you want.

### Payload

Using my sample information above, I'd make a `POST` call to `https://us7.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/1295ff8fdb/members/` with a JSON payload that looks like this:

```
{
    "email_address": "hugo@leggett.fr",
    "status": "subscribed",
    "merge_fields": {
        "FNAME": "Hugo",
        "LNAME": "Dumoulin",
        "PHONE": "0606060606"
    }
}
```

### Sample Request

So, if you're using the HTTP client linked above, the code might look like this:

```
<?php
use Cake\Network\Http\Client;

$http = new Client();

$subscriberData = array(
    'email_address' => 'hugo@leggett.fr',
    'status' => 'subscribed',
    'merge_fields' => array(
        'FNAME' => 'Hugo',
        'LNAME' => 'Dumoulin',
        'PHONE' => '0606060606'
    )
);

$response = $http->post(
  'https://us7.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/1295ff8fdb/members/',
  json_encode($subscriberData),
  array(
    'type' => 'json'
    'auth' => array(
      'type' => 'basic', 
      'username' => 'anything', 
      'password' => $MAILCHIMP_API_KEY
    )
  )
);
```

Now, if the user has already been subscribed, MailChimp will return a 4xx error and this code doesn't account for any other error conditions, so definitely use this as a jumping-off point rather than a complete solution, but it should get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for this detailed explanation. Indeed this seems to be the right way, I will give it a try as soon as I can. Thank you very much!

Comment: Great answer but it does not show how the authentication with the API key is done.

Comment: @doonot -- there are other questions that explain how to use Authentication with MailChimp that may be more thorough, but I've updated this answer to include that here, as well, specific to CakePHP.